# Product category function in codeigniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm making a website in CodeIgniter and I'm trying to make a menu bar with all the categories, and when you click on a certain category it must show all the products that are in that category but its not really working.

When I open the category.php view page instead of the side menu bar there are really big white blank links that lead to nothing. Also when I click on one of those links I get an error. This is the error:

```
An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

Also this is the error message when I load up the category.php view:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/allecadeaus.php

Line Number: 26

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/allecadeaus.php
Line: 26
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/AlleCadeausController.php
Line: 12
Function: view

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

The category.php view page looks like this: [image]

allecadeaus.php file:

```
<?php   include_once ('templates/header.php');  ?>

<!-- Alle cadeaus gele title bovenaan pagina -->

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 bg-warning" style="font-size:25px">
            <center>Alle cadeaus</center>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>

 <hr />

<br>

<!-- Cadeau categorie side menu -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="categorymenu">
                    <center>  <h3>Categorieën</h3> </center>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <?php foreach ($category() as $row) : ?>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                               <a href="<?php echo base_url('Product/category/'.$row->id);?>"> <?php echo $row->name; ?></a>

                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>




<!-- Laat cadeau zien op alle cadeaus pagina -->
<div class="col-md-8">
<?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div id="product">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product['product_foto_thumb']; ?>">
        </a>
        <div class="product_naam"><?php echo $product['product_naam']; ?></div>
        <div class="ophaal_plaats">
           <?php  echo $product['ophaal_plaats']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="aangeboden_door">
            <p>Aangeboden door: Peter</p>
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>


<?php endforeach; ?>

</div>



<div class="clearfix"></div>

 <?php   include_once ('templates/footer.php');  ?>
```

This is my category.php view page:

```
<?php   include_once ('templates/header.php');  ?>

<!-- Alle cadeaus gele title bovenaan pagina -->

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 bg-warning" style="font-size:25px">
            <center>Alle cadeaus</center>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>

 <hr />

<br>

<!-- Cadeau categorie side menu -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="categorymenu">
                    <center>  <h3>Categorieën</h3> </center>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $category) : ?>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                               <a href="<?php echo base_url('Product/category/'.$category->id);?>"> <?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>

                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>




<!-- Laat cadeau zien op alle cadeaus pagina -->
<div class="col-md-8">
<?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div id="product">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product['product_foto_thumb']; ?>">
        </a>
        <div class="product_naam"><?php echo $product['product_naam']; ?></div>
        <div class="ophaal_plaats">
           <?php  echo $product['ophaal_plaats']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="aangeboden_door">
            <p>Aangeboden door: Peter</p>
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>


<?php endforeach; ?>

</div>



<div class="clearfix"></div>

 <?php   include_once ('templates/footer.php');  ?>
```

This is the function that I have in my Product.php controller file:

```
public function category($id)
 {
  $data['title'] = 'Category';
  $data['page'] = 'Product/category';
  $data['category'] = $this->Category_model->findByCategory($id);
  $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->findByCategory($id);
  $this->load->view('category', $data);
 }
```

These are the functions in my product model (Product_model.php):

```
public function get_categories(){
        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->from('categories'); 
        $query = $this->db->get(); 
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }


    public function findAll(){
        return $this->db->get('product')->result();
    }

     public function findByCategory($category_id){
         $this->db->where('category_id', $category_id);
        return $this->db->get('product')->result();
    }
```

And this is my Category_model.php file:

```
<?php


class Category_model extends CI_Model {

    public function findAll(){
        return $this->db->get('category')->result();
    }

    public function find($id){
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        return $this->db->get('category')->row();
    }

}
?>
```

Some database information:

```
Table 1: products
-product_id
-product_naam
-product_beschrijving
-user_id
-category_id

table 2: categories: 2 columns:
1.id
2.name
```

This is how my categories table looks:

```
id  name

1   Cosmetica
2   Antiek en kunst
3   Voor kinderen
4   Apparatuur
5   Boeken
6   Muziek en instrumenten
7   Spellen
8   Sieraden
9   Overige cadeaus
10  Sport
```

Comment: Underneath that big white space there is an error message.  In your browser do `view page source` and view the HTML source code to see what the error message is saying.  Furthermore, enable error logging and review your error logs to see what the problem is. There are probably multiple issues, but once you can actually see what they are you can work through them

Comment: Its this error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/allecadeaus.php

Line Number: 26

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/allecadeaus.php
Line: 26
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/AlleCadeausController.php
Line: 12
Function: view

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: well, check views/allecadeaus.php Line Number: 26

Comment: This line is not right somehow: <a href="<?php echo base_url('Product/category/'.$category['id']);?>"> <?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>

Comment: Can you spot a mistake

Comment: yes, its $category[id], which I have no idea how you are assessing. please google: "Trying to get property of non-object", you'll find a lot of hints on arrays, etc...

Comment: and what about this:  <a href="<?php echo base_url('Product/category/'.$category->id);?>">

Answer (score 0):

Your category names/id's contain characters that are not allowed with your current `permitted_uri_chars` configuration in the **config.php** file.

Go to your config.php file (`application\config\config.php`) and give the `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` option the value: `a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\=`

This will allow almost all common characters.

Comment: Could you give an example of how your categorie names/id look?

Comment: Ill edit my question and show how my categorie table looks

Comment: Did you print out the result that `$result = $query->result_array();` gives you?

Comment: No sir I didn't

Comment: Please debug everything to make sure you get the results that you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to chnage in your view file replace this code

```
<?php foreach ($category as $row) : ?>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                               <a href="<?php echo base_url('Product/category/'.$row->id);?>"> <?php echo $row->name; ?></a>

                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Getting this error now: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined function category()

Filename: views/allecadeaus.php

Line Number: 24

Backtrace:

Comment: this line: <?php foreach (category() as $row) : ?>

Comment: and also you are calling wrong function in Category_model `$this->Category_model->findByCategory($id);`

Comment: Getting this error now: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: category

Filename: views/allecadeaus.php

Line Number: 24

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/allecadeaus.php
Line: 24
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/AlleCadeausController.php
Line: 12
Function: view

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: where is the `allecadeaus.php` file?

Comment: What do you mean? I need to put this line : $this->Category_model->findByCategory($id) in my Category_model file?

Comment: Its contains the same code as category.php file. Ill add it to my question

Comment: I added allecadeaus.php file to my question

Comment: change this function to Category_model '' `public function find($id)` TO `public function findByCategory($id)`

Comment: It still says : Message: Undefined variable: category

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Function name must be a string

Filename: views/allecadeaus.php

Line Number: 24

Backtrace:

Comment: this line is wrong it says:  <?php foreach ($category() as $row) : ?>

Comment: i have alredy changed so plese chage it to `<?php foreach ($category as $row) : ?>` remove ()

Comment: Still 2 errors sir: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/allecadeaus.php

Line Number: 24

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/allecadeaus.php
Line: 24
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/AlleCadeausController.php
Line: 12
Function: view

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: and this error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: category

Filename: views/allecadeaus.php

Line Number: 24

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/allecadeaus.php
Line: 24
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/AlleCadeausController.php
Line: 12
Function: view

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: I never define $category

Comment: you can try this `$this->db->get('category')->result();` category model return result() instead of row()

Comment: I putted this : $this->db->get('category')->result(); in my findAll function and still the same errors unfortunately

Comment: not in find all change in `findByCategory($id)` function beacause you are calling this  function

Comment: you know solution?